# How can i resolve insecure connection on mozilla firefox 54 in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I have used Selenium 3.4 along with Geckodriver v0.18.0.

To handle the SSL certificates in Firefox I used capabilities of Selenium Webdriver:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
myprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
myprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

But still it is showing an insecure connection after firefox launch

Comment: Can you give us some clue about the URL in use? More over I am yet to see you using the capabilities of Selenium Webdriver. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per the question without any reference to the url where the SSL certificates are blocking, here is the minimum code block to bypass the **`SSL Certificate`**. In this code block we will use the **`DesiredCapabilities`** Class to set the **`CapabilityType`** of **`ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS`** to **`true`** as follows:

```
package certificateIssue;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CertificateIssue_Firefox 
{

    @Test
    public void handleCertificate()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
        driver.get("http://www.cacert.org/");

    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.